# If $x^n→x$ component-wise then $f(x^n)→f(x)$ component-wise?

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $(x^n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \ell^2$ such that it converges to $x \in \ell^2$ component-wise, i. e. for all $k \in \mathbb N: x^n_k→x_k,n→\infty$. Now let $f:\ell^2→\ell^2$ be continious. I would like to get
$$x^n→x \text{ compnent-wise} \Rightarrow f(x^n)→f(x) \text{ component-wise}.$$

By the latter I mean
\begin{align}\lim_{n→ \infty}f(x^n)=\lim_{n→ \infty}f(x^n_1,x^n_2,...) \overset{?}=f(\lim_{n→ \infty}x^n_1,\lim_{n→ \infty}x^n_2,...)=f(x_1,x_2,...)=f(x) \tag Q.
\end{align}
Is there a known definition, topology, or any other way to get this kind of "component-wise" convergence? Under what conditions do we can get this kind of convergence.

My attempt would be the following: Since $f$ is continuous it is separate continuous, meaning that if we fix every component of the argument but the $i$-th one we get a one-dimensional continuous function: $f(x)=f(x_1,...,\cdot,x_{i+1},...)$. Did this work for $\rm Q$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your map $f$ linear?

Comment: Not necessarily but we can assume that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a metric giving a componentwise convergence. It's a product metric:

- $X:=\prod_{i\in \Bbb N} X_i$;
- $d_i$ is a metric on $X_i$;
- $\tilde d_i$ is an equivalent and bounded (by a common constant for all $i$) metric to $d_i$, for example $\tilde d=d/(1+d)$ or $\tilde d=\max\{1,d\}$.
- $d\colon X\times X\to \Bbb R$ is a product metric:
  $$d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1{2^i}\cdot\tilde d_i(x_i,y_i).$$

Then $d(x^n,x)\to 0$ iff $d_i(x^n_i,x_i)\to 0$ for all $i$.

Using $\ell^2$ norm for componentwise convergence is not good. We know that if $x^n\to x$ in $\ell^2$ then $x^n\to x$ componentwise, but not vice-versa.

Consider $f\colon \ell^2\to\ell^2$, $f(x)=(\|x\|_{\ell^2},0,0,0,\ldots)$. Then $f$ is continuous. The sequence $e^n=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$ is convergent componentwise to $0$ but $\|e^n\|=1$, so $f(e^n)\not\to f(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not sure if I understood you correctly. I am not using the $\ell^2$-norm at all so why is this a problem?

Comment: @Trumpet, you used in the sentence: Now let $f:\ell^2→\ell^2$ be continuous. Continuity means that if $\|x_n-x\|_{\ell^2}\to 0$ then $\|f(x_n)-f(x)\|_{\ell^2}\to 0$.